# Remove files in a directory with ls grep and rm

Tags: grep, ls, rm

I've a bash file on my project root with this line

```
$ ls | grep -P '^some_pattern_matching_regex_goeshere.txt$' | xargs rm -f
```

The above line removes all the `.txt` files from the project root but when I push all the .txt files to another folder e.g **process_logs/** and try the same commands with `ls`, `grep` and `rm` its doesn't work.

This is what I tried but not worked to removed files on the **process_logs** directory.

```
 $ ls process_logs/ | grep -P '^some_pattern_matching_regex_goeshere.txt$' | xargs rm -f
```

**N.B**: I've also tried the command with simple regex pattern like
 `ls process_logs/ | grep -P '^*.txt$' | xargs rm -f` to remove files from directory but It doesn't work though.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `find` instead. If you don't want `find` to be recursive, you can use depth options:

```
find /process_logs -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name 'some_shell_glob_pattern_here' -delete
```

Parsing the output of `ls` is not recommended because `ls` is not always accurate because `ls` prints a human-readable version of the filename, which may not match the actual filename. For more info see the [parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) wiki article.

Comment: `find` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I agree with **using find is the better option**. But I want to add why your command is not working.

Your command:

```
$ ls process_logs/ | grep -P '^some_pattern_matching_regex_goeshere.txt$' | xargs rm -f
```

`ls` outputs filenames **without the path**. But you don't add the path to `rm`. So it will try to delete file names from your subdirectory in your current/ root directory.

Try

```
$ cd process_logs/; ls | grep -P '^some_pattern_matching_regex_goeshere.txt$' | xargs rm -f
```

Or

```
$ ls process_logs/ | grep -P '^some_pattern_matching_regex_goeshere.txt$' | xargs -i rm -f "process_logs/{}"
```

Comment: Though I'll use **find** but your answer is very clear to me why my approach with ls doesn't work, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple shell filename globbing pattern, just use that.

E.g. (the `*` may be replaced by some more precise pattern),

```
rm -f process_logs/*.txt
```

or, if there are hundred of thousands of files, use `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\0' process_logs/*.txt | xargs -0 rm -f
```

If you absolutely *need* to use a regular expression, GNU `find` may do that with

```
find process_logs -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '\.txt$' -delete
```

Note that the `-regex` predicate matches against the complete pathname, not just the filename portion at the end (which is why I anchored the expression to the end of the pathname with `$`).  See also the `-regextype` option in the GNU `find` manual.